# Pentaho cde excel export after change table header dont take new header

Tags: jquery, export, pentaho

I have a Pentaho table component with these column headers:

`|toto/a |toto/b |titi/a |titi/b |`

After modifying column headers with jquery in table post execution, I have these new headers displayed:

`|toto |titi |
 |a |b |a |b |`

But when I use the export button or the table.queryState.exportData function, the exported file still with |toto/a |  toto/b | titi/a | titi/b| header.

Any idea for having the displayed columns in the export file?

Comment: Are you running \jquery code in pre-execution?

Comment: i do  
`function f() {
        this.chartDefinition.colHeaders = [];
        this.chartDefinition.colTypes = [];
        this.chartDefinition.colFormats = [];}`  
 in pre execution and Jquery in post execution.